# Advent of Code 2020 Day 1 in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

This is a Clojurescript solution to parts 1 and 2 of [Day 1](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1) of Advent of Code 2020.

This code is written in Clojurescript to run on Node.js. It can be run simply using [lumo](https://github.com/anmonteiro/lumo) and this command: `lumo filename.cljs`.

Here's a short version of the problem statement:

Part 1. Given a list of numbers, find the two entries that sum to 2020 and then multiply those two numbers together.

```
(ns day-01.core
  (:require [clojure.string]))

(def fs (js/require "fs"))

(def entries
  (set
   (map js/parseInt
        (clojure.string/split-lines
         (.readFileSync fs "puzzle.input" "utf8")))))

(println (reduce *
                 (filter (fn [entry]
                           (contains? entries (- 2020 entry))) entries)))
```

Part 2: what is the product of the **three** entries that sum to 2020?

```
;; Same boilerplate

(def match
  (first
   (filter #(= 2020 (reduce + %))
           (for [x entries y entries z entries] [x y z]))))

(println (reduce * match))
```